# How to combine many CS files into a DLL file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, edit, dotpeek

Basically what I'm trying to do is this:

1: Take an existing DLL file.
2: Edit some C# scripts inside. I'm doing this by using DotPeek to open in Visual Studio.

3: After editing the files, put them back into the original DLL file so the program works fine (modified by me).

So now I'm stuck on the last step, getting the files back into the DLL file so the program works. Any ideas? THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Extract all the source files from the dll, assemble a .csproj, and build it the same way as any other dll. That's the way I've done it. I'm sure there's some way to squirt individual types into the dll, but depending on the complexity of the dll, my method might be easiest (or completely impractical)

Comment: "build it the same way as any other dll". Perhaps I should clarify that while I've made lots of APK's and .EXE with Unity3D I haven't done .DLL yet :( Could you please clarify how you do it? Means a lot, thanks!

Comment: Open visual studio, create a library project, and drag in the source files.